# Object Initializer Syntax C#

Tags: c#, syntax, initialization

Which one is the proper syntax when initializing objects?
All the samples are working but I don't know which and when to use each syntax. I always use **Syntax 1**. Does using this syntax have any advantage over the other syntaxes?

```
public class X { 
    public string Y { get; set; }
}

// Syntax 1
var z = new X () { Y = "Sample Text" };

// Syntax 2
var z = new X { Y = "Sample Text" };

// Syntax 3
var z = new X();
z.Y = "Sample Text";
```

Comment: Syntax1 and Syntax2 are the same. Basically there is not performance difference between all 3. It's just a syntax sugar to use object initializers. You can use any of three. Its just the way you write your code

Comment: I use the one that has the fewest characters, as long as it's readable. I would say just choose the one you prefer and stick to that (i.e. be consistent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all the "proper" (and valid) syntax. Pick your favourite

The first 2 examples use *Object Initializers*

[Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

> Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or
>   properties of an object at creation time without having to invoke a
>   constructor followed by lines of assignment statements.

The 3rd is constructing the object first and assigning the `Y` property in a separate step

--

The compiled IL to the initalizer form

```
    IL_0000: newobj instance void C/X::.ctor()
    IL_0005: dup
    IL_0006: ldstr "Sample Text"
    IL_000b: callvirt instance void C/X::set_Y(string)
    IL_0010: pop
```

---

The compiled  IL to the explicit declaration

```
    IL_0000: newobj instance void C/X::.ctor()
    IL_0005: ldstr "Sample Text"
    IL_000a: callvirt instance void C/X::set_Y(string)
```

The difference (in this example) is a `dup` and `pop` off the stack

In summary there is no appreciable difference